# Build apk from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I'm create simple project VS 2015 and Apache Cordova and when tray build apk file option create app packages is disabled.

Link http ://postimg.org/image/4sxlicjx3/

I don't have idea what is problem.

Any solution....

Comment: Don't post error messages as images. Includes the error messages _as text_ in the question itself.

Comment: @Michael I don't have error only option is disabled in visaul studio 2015